# Create a trigger after update to loop through each updated column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to track all changes for specific tables.
So I want to have a trigger to fire when table get updated, for each updated field I want to insert a row in my audit log table with the column old value and new value.

For example lets say I have a employee table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Current] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

And a log table like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Logs]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Puser] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [WinUser] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [Computer] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [Type] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [ObjectType] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [ObjectName] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [Action] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [RecordID] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [FIeldName] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [OldValue] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [NewValue] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ParentName] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ParentID] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [RowDump] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

And I change the password and active column for an employee, I would like to enter 2 rows into the `Logs` table (including the employee id in recordid, column name in fieldname, oldvalue, newvalue)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your DDL implies you are storing passwords as plain text; this is a huge concern. Always salt and hash passwords when you store them.

Comment: As per the question guide, please show us what you have tried and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **best** method to do this kind of thing is to use existing tools in SQL Server, such as [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), and [SQL Auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

---

However, if you *really* want to roll your own logging, the following should get you started.

> It's unclear what some of your logging columns are supposed to represent so I've omitted them. It also seems like overkill.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.LogChanges ON dbo.Employee
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
    RETURN;    -- bail early if no rows
    
INSERT dbo.Logs (
    TimeStamp,
    WinUser,
    Computer,
    Action,
    OldValue,
    NewValue,
    ParentID
)
SELECT
    GETUTCDATE(),
    SUSER_NAME(),
    HOST_NAME(),
    IIF(i.ID IS NOT NULL, IIF(d.ID IS NOT NULL, 'U', 'I'), 'D'),
    v.oldVal,
    v.newVal,
    ISNULL(i.ID, d.ID)
FROM inserted i
FULL JOIN deleted d ON d.ID = i.ID    -- full join on primary key
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (i.FirstName, d.FirstName),    -- unpivot all columns
    (i.LastName, d.LastName),
    (i.[Current], d.[Current]),
    (i.Password, d.Password)
) v(newVal, oldVal)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT v.newVal EXCEPT SELECT v.oldVal);    -- null-aware comparison
```

If the column types are mixed then you should cast at least the first value in the `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to `sql_variant`.

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=53dcdc4eb54d49ef4306223b51f4b70b)

I note that some of your data types are questionable, such as nullable columns, lengths, and object and username columns should be `sysname`. Plain-text passwords are also a bad idea.

Comment: This will still produce rows even if, say, firstname is updated, no?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis What do you mean exactly? If `firstname` is updated to the same value, or if only another column is updated, then no it won't produce a row for `firstname`. Note the final `WHERE`

Comment: @Charlieface Interesting , I just grasped it. I was comparing this to a COLUMNS_UPDATED approach.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Problem with that is that it only tells you which columns are *present* in the `UPDATE` not which actually changed

Comment: "Actually changed" has multiple viewpoints, though, right? I guess for a situation like OP's, they probably wouldn't want the cases where oldvalue=newvalue. Someone like a dev might still want to know, for example because of triggers fired, or maybe to check which query ran.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis A real dev or DBA wouldn't use this, they would use one of the options I mentioned, or possibly an XEvent session. This is just an exercise in "how to roll your own trace"